# How long does the site save an unfinished answer?

Tags: support

I noticed yesterday that after a certain amount of time, this site tells me that my answer-in-progress has been saved. If I delay completing my answer until the next day, does what I have written disappear? Apparently, this is what happens, though I am not sure. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how long it takes to save, but also check out [Github Gists](https://gist.github.com/) (select 'Markdown' as the language) - you can work on posts there and save them. And there's always text editors and local copies.

Comment: Thanks for the link to GIT. In future, I may just give it a whirl. Don

Answer (score 6):

MSO has [detailed description of how the drafts feature works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/145951).

It looks like the answer is "1 week". Also, opening a new post in a new tab will clear the draft version of any previously open tab.

Comment: I'm "almost positive" my incomplete answer was saved automatically yesterday, but upon returning to the OP's question today, my incomplete answer had disappeared. May have been a glitch. Hey, here's an idea: could BHB give a member some sort of reminder (on his or her profile page) that he or she has an unfinished answer in the system?

Comment: @rhetorician Are you on the same computer/browser? I think it is saved in LocalStorage in your browser, not on the server. I'm not sure on that though.

Comment: Sorry, Caleb. I'm not what you would call computer savvy. Hence, I'm not clear as to the meaning of what you just said. You needn't take time to tutor me, since I have a friend locally who can tell me what you mean. Thanks. Don

Comment: @rhetorician Ignore the second part of that, just answer the first. Are you using the same browser and computer right now as you were when you wrote what you think got saved as a draft?

Comment: Yes, I am. Don, rhetorician

Comment: @rhetorician Well then never mind that.

Comment: I don't know if it still does this, but once I started an answer at home, logged in on break at work, and there was my work in progress. You could have knocked me over with a feather.